# Delete certain pictures using the date and time information in the filename

Tags: image, date, batch-file, filenames, delete-file

I have a folder with 552k pictures. (552115 to be precise).

They are from a camera that took X photos every day over a few years, which I later would use to create a timelapse.

The problem is that the guy who set this up configured it to take a picture every two minutes 24/7.

Now I have a bunch of files I need to delete.

I only need about 1-5 pics between 09:00 and 15:00 each day and definitely not those taken at night.

The filename is `Name-11-04-01_19-25-17-01.jpg`

The filename is `Name-YY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS-MS.jpg`

Date and time information is also available in the metadata.

I would prefer if this could be done in Batch or PowerShell, but I'm open to other scripting languages ​​if it can be done easier than using batch/ps.

I appreciate your response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick. You must adjust the `"yourFolder"` to point to your folder containing the files. It assumes all of your files have an extension, which you failed to show in your question.

The script creates a SAVE folder, and then attempts to move 4 files for each day into the SAVE folder. It looks for the earliest file each day for the hours of 9, 11, 13, and 15 where the minutes starts with 0.

After the script has run, and you confirm you have what you need, you can delete all remaining files from the original folder if you want, and keep the files in the SAVE folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd "yourFolder"
mkdir save
dir /b /a-d * | findstr /re "_09-0.-..-..\..* _11-0.-..-..\..* _13-0.-..-..\..* _15-0.-..-..\..*" >files.txt
for /f %%F in (files.txt) do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  if not exist "save\!name:~0,-9!-*" move "%%F" save
)
```

You should be able to modify the FINDSTR search patterns to adjust the number of files per day. For example, to keep one file per day, you could use a single string: `"_09-0.-..-..\..*"`. One advantage of this is the light level and direction should be more consistent throughout the time lapse.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Nice script, but when it looks for the earliest file each day for the hours of 9, 11, 13, and 15 where the minutes starts with 0, it takes all these: 11-01, 11-03, 11-05, 11-07 and 11-09. So i get 5 x 4 files instead of 4.
Is there a way to only get one out of those (Only the earliest)?

Comment: @MokiTa - Did you run the script? Yes the FINDSTR will preserve multiple files for a given hour. But the IF NOT EXIST within the DO clause will only preserve one file per hour per day. The FINDSTR is an attempt to limit the number of files that are iterated so as to dramatically improve performance. The DO clause should give the desired result, regardless of how many files are iterated.

Comment: Hm, then there must be something wrong. Yes, I ran the script. It only pipes the name of the pictures to "files.txt" and then moves "files.txt" to the save folder.

EDIT: You missed `/F` in `for %%F in (files.txt)`. 
Now it moves the files to the "save" folder, but the folder contains the same amount of files as the FINDSTR preserved.

Comment: @MokiTa - Doh! Yes, I forgot the /F option. I also was inconsistent with my variable name: "name" vs. "file". It should be fixed now. Don't forget to move all the files back to the original location before running the fixed script.

Comment: Anyone can make such a small mistake like that :) 
Thanks man, it works flawlessly now. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Powershell over batch files. I have written the solution here as a powershell script
Obviously test this thoroughly before running it on your prized photos.

```
get-childitem -filter "*_*.jpg" | foreach ($_) {$hour = [int]$_.name.Substring($_.name.indexof("_")+1, 2); if($hour -lt 09 -or $hour -ge 15) {remove-item $_.fullname}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tested the script, but the only thing it does is deleting every picture except those between 09 and 15. I still got 180 pictures between 09 and 15. It helped a lot, but not enough.